# JQuery image to div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, attr

I'v got multiple div's with thumbnails, the div also includes an inner div with an standard picture, clicking on a thumb will show the picture in the inner div.

The problem: When I open another div the last opened picture will still show.

**JQuery**

```
$('.thumbsmall img').click(function(){
    $(".imageshow").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.src));
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <h2>3D automotive visualisatie</h2>
    <div class="imageshow"></div>
    <p>Visualisatie 3D automotive</p>
    <ul class="list-inline item-details">
        <li>Klant: <strong><a>Eigen project</a></strong></li>
        <li>Datum: <strong><a>WIP</a></strong></li>
        <li>Wat?: <strong><a>3D productie</a></strong></li>
        <li>Tags: <a>3D, vray, automotive, hdri</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Sluit
    </button>
</div>
<div class="thumbsmall">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/3d15.png" alt="3d design"></li>
        <li><img src="img/3d3.png" alt="3d design"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Link**
http://robbyquintiens.be
Situated in the portfolio section

Thanks :)

Comment: `$("<img>")` is not a valid selector

Comment: try once:
First, Inside the click function clear the current image existing inside the div.
Second, then insert the line which you're using:
$(".imageshow").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.src));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
$('.thumbsmall img').click(function(){
    $(".imageshow").html($('img.class-of-the-other-image').prop("src", $(this).prop('src')));//newer jquery
    $(".imageshow").html($('img.class-of-the-other-image').attr("src", $(this).attr('src')));// older jquery
})
```

Don't forget to put the class-of-the-other-image on the html or change for the class name you want to.